# Stuck at some level of think different @ android

Tags: think-different

I have been stuck on one of the levels, and could not solve it. Here is the puzzle:

5682 = 714; 9516 = 156; 3498 = 1113; 8257 = ?

[image: 5682: 714, 9516: 156, 3498: 1113, 8257: ???]

Comment: I understand that you are trying to display the puzzle exactly as it is presented to you, but its just a number game. Text is all you need to accurately display the puzzle. The image detracts, though, what with the giant resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work out the answers by adding the first and last numbers of the initial number together, then adding the middle two numbers together, before simply joining the two solutions.

5682 = 714; 5 + 2 = 7, 6 + 8 = 14.
9516 = 156; 9 + 6 = 15, 5 + 1 = 6.
3498 = 1113; 3 + 8 = 11, 4 + 9 = 13.
8257 = 157; 8 + 7 = 15, 2 + 5 = 7.

**The solution is 157.**

Comment: Thanks bro it worked. I was stuck on this one for past 200 hrs.

Comment: But there is a typing error. It shoul be 157.